# Asynchronous Ajax Calls giving "Caution: request is not finished yet in chrome" when performing operation in Partial View Page

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, asynchronous, asp.net-ajax

I have a `HistoryController.cs`, `index.cshtml` , some `javascript` code and three partial views.

In `index.cshtml` I have three partial views in the form of tablist which are hidden at first.
When I click a button in `index.cshtml` it calls a javascript function to calls three ajax calls respectively for three partial views.

**Current Behavior:**
But when one partial view loads and if I perform a operation on that partial view in the developer tools it shows **Caution: request is not finished yet in chrome**. It waits for other partial views and then performs the operation.

**Expected Behavior:**
I don't want to wait for the other partial views to load first and then do some interaction.
If the first partial view loads, I want to perform some interaction while the other views load in background.

**Index.cshtml**

```
<input type="button" id="HistorySearchButton" value="Search" class="buttoncommon" />

<div id="historyPane">
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul role="tablist">

            <li id="ClientHistoryDivTab" role="tab" aria-controls="companyHistoryDetailsTab">
                <a id="companyHistoryDetailsTabLink" href="#companyHistoryDetailsTab" class="ui-tabs-anchor tabs-bg" role="presentation">Client History</a>
            </li>

            <li id="CompanySubscriptionDivTab"  role="tab" aria-controls="companySubHistoryDetailsTab">
                <a id="companySubHistoryDetailsTabLink" href="#companySubHistoryDetailsTab" class="ui-tabs-anchor tabs-bg" role="presentation"> Company Sub History</a>
            </li>

            <li id="UserSubscriptionDivTab"  role="tab" aria-controls="userSubHistoryDetailsTab">
                <a id="userSubHistoryDetailsTabLink" href="#userSubHistoryDetailsTab"  role="presentation">User History</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="companyHistoryDetailsTab" class="partial-container" style="display:none"></div>
<div id="companySubHistoryDetailsTab" class="partial-container" style="display:none"></div>
<div id="userSubHistoryDetailsTab" class="partial-container" style="display:none"></div>
```

**Java Script code**

```
$("#HistorySearchButton").click(function () {
    LoadCompanyHistory();
    $("#companyHistoryDetailsTab").show();
    LoadCompanySubscriptionHistory();
    LoadUserSubscriptionHistory();
    });


 function LoadCompanyHistory() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/History/GetCompanyDetailsHistory',
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            traditional: true,
            async: true, 
            // some code
            success: function (data) {
                $("#companyHistoryDetailsTab").html(data);
            },
            // some code
        });
 }

  function LoadCompanySubscriptionHistory() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/History/GetCompanySubcriptionHistory',
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            traditional: true,
            async: true,
            // some code
            success: function (data) {
                $("#companySubHistoryDetailsTab").html(data);
            },
            // some code
            });
 }

   function LoadUserSubscriptionHistory() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/History/GetUserSubcriptionHistory',
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            traditional: true,
            async: true,
            // some code
            success: function (data) {
                $("#userSubHistoryDetailsTab").html(data);
            }, 
            // some code
        });
 }
```

**History Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetCompanyDetailsHistory()
{
    // some logic
    return PartialView("_ClientDetailsHistory", model);
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetCompanySubcriptionHistory()
{
    // some logic
    return PartialView("_CompanySubscriptionHistory", model);
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetUserSubcriptionHistory()
{
    // some logic
    return PartialView("_UserSubscriptionHistory", model);
}
```